# Sequelize return wrong result

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I use sequelize with Postgresql, if i run the follow query in pgadmin postgresql client, i have correct values:

```sql
select students->>'name', students->>'birthday', u.created_at
from users u, json_array_elements(u.information->'Section B') students 
where u.created_at::date = '2019-08-01T00:00:00.000Z'
```

My  Students table is this:

```
id - serial2
students - json
created_at: timestamp with time zone
```

When i ran the same query as follow in sequelize i have an empty result:

```
sequelize.query(`select students->>'name', students->>'birthday', u.created_at
from users u, json_array_elements(u.information->'Section B') students 
where u.created_at::date = :created_at'`, {
            type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT,
            replacements: {created_at: where_date }
```

With  `where_date = 2019-08-01T00:00:00.000Z`

In my model definition i have `timestamps: true` already try using `timestamps: false`, same empty result.

Comment: in your sequelize config file. try add  dialectOptions: {
    useUTC: false 
  },

Comment: I have: 
```javascript
 sequelize = new Sequelize(
      `connection_string`,
      {
        quoteIdentifiers: false,
        dialectOptions: {
          useUTC: false,
        },
      }
    ); `
```
Same empty result. thank you

Comment: what is the query generated from sequelize in your console ?

Comment: is this:
```sql
Executing (default): select students->>'name', students->>'birthday', u.created_at
from users u, json_array_elements(u.information->'Section B') students 
where u.created_at::date = '2019-08-01T00:00:00.000Z;```

Answer (score 0):

In my case just was mismatching database configs, so I was querying one database in pgadmin and pointing to another one into the application. Kind it obvious but still worth to take a look onto credentials.